# Reflecting points in an RGB image over a reflection line (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, reflection, line

I have an RGB image of size MxNx3. Let's imagine we have a reflection line somewhere in the bottom half of the image. How do I reflect all the points above the line onto the line? I know what I need to do but I can't get it right on MATLAB. Thanks for any help.

For example, in the image below the blue line is the reflection line.

[image]

Comment: Is the line horizontal?

Comment: Yes. But its not a straight line.

Comment: @SavK Er... horizontal but not straight??

Comment: @LuisMendo haha yeah I laughed for a second on that too! But I think I got the idea :)

Comment: Oh sorry. Its not horizontal. Forgot that it had to be parallel to be called horizontal. My bad.

Comment: I think an image would really help :)

Comment: @SavK Not getting any *straight* ideas yet ;) So we are supposed to detect the blue line too? Can we get help on that from you?

Comment: Yes it does. It would also help to know how the line is defined, but I think I have a crooked idea ;)

Comment: @beaker The way I am doing it right now, I am making a duplicate of the image and segmenting out the part below the blue line using `roipoly`. So everything above the blue line will be blank and top of what remains is used as the 'reflection line'. Makes sense?

Comment: Detecting that line would be one task in itself.

Comment: @Divakar I had assumed that the line was already known, but perhaps I was mistaken.

Comment: @beaker This calls for a bounty ;)

Comment: I mean, once you have the line defined, it's simple for each column to copy the data that's above the line to the image below the line (but reversed). I was thinking there might be some perspective requirements  going on, but to know *where* to put the line is a whole new bag of requirements.

Comment: @beaker Suppose you have the line defined, I can't copy all the data from above the line. I need to go through each point in each column above the line because it is possible for the points to go outside the  image boundary. How do I go through each point in each column in an RGB image? Two for loops?

Comment: Interesting problem. How exactly is the blue line defined? An array?

Comment: @SavK When using `roipoly` Can I tell the user of it to select exactly two points on the left side to represent my left side border and exactly two points on the right side  for the right side border? There could be as many points as needed for the rest of it though.

Comment: @Divakar Border of what?

Comment: With `roipoly`, it would create a mask right? And from the mask I need to get the line right?

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro Defining the blue line was a task of its own. I tried explaining it to beaker in one of the comments above. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: @Divakar Yes pretty much. I did an extra step and used the mask on the image and then tried to get the line from the the image which I used the mask on.

Comment: @SavK Were you able to get the line coordinates from it? Or else how did you get the line?

Comment: @SavK I'm not sure I understood it right. The line was created by hand? My question is: right now, how is the line represented on Matlab?

Comment: @Divakar I haven't got the line coordinates yet from it. The line in the picture was done using the `line` command just to demonstrate what I needed.

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro Right now the line is not explicitly represented. I have a duplicate image in which everything above the blue is black pixels. So of the image that remains, the first non-black pixels in each column is considered to be the line. Hope that helps :)

Comment: @SavK Before I get more confused, I need to clarify few things - Can I assume that the mask from `roipoly` is my starting point. If so, Can I go one little step back and while selecting the mask using `roipoly`, ask user to select exactly two points on the left side to represent my left side border and exactly two points on the right side for the right side border of the mask?

Comment: @SavK So `line[c]` in my answer is just row of the first non-black pixel in column `c` in your duplicate image.

Comment: @Divakar Yes you can assume that the mask is the starting point and yes you can ask the user if that'll help.

Comment: @SavK Just curious if any of the answers worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code**

```
%%// Read input image
img =imread(IMG_FILEPATH);

%%// Let user select the mask, top of which will basically act 
%%// as the reflection line
figure,imshow(img)
[mask,xi,yi] = roipoly(img);

%%// Remove the last element as that is same as the first one
xi(end)=[];
yi(end)=[];

%%// Find the two corner points each on the left and right sides of the mask
pt_matrix = [xi yi]
[val,ind] = sort(xi)
left_two_pts = pt_matrix(ind(1:2),:)
right_two_pts = pt_matrix(ind(end-1:end),:)
four_pts = round([left_two_pts;right_two_pts])

%%// Remove a 5x5 neighborhood around the four corners, so that biggest
%%// blob that is the line could be separated out
BW1 = edge(mask,'canny');
for k = 1:4
    BW1(four_pts(k,2)-2:four_pts(k,2)+2,four_pts(k,1)-2:four_pts(k,2)+1) = 0;
end

%%// Get the biggest blob that is the reflection line
[L, num] = bwlabel(BW1);
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,L(:),1:num));
[~,ind] = max(counts);
BW1 = (L==ind);

%%// Connect the endpoints of the line to left and right sides of the image
xlimit = [find(sum(BW1,1),1) find(sum(BW1,1),1,'last')];
[row1,col1] = ind2sub(size(BW1),find(BW1));
BW1(row1(1),1:col1(1)-1)=1;
BW1(row1(end),col1(end)+1:end)=1;

%%// Select only one per column for the reflection
[xt0,yt0] = find(BW1);
[yt1,a2,a3] =unique(yt0,'first');
xt1=xt0(a2);
sz1 = size(BW1,1)-xt1;

%%// Perform the reflection
for k = 1:numel(yt1)
    img(xt1(k):end,k,:) = img(xt1(k):-1:xt1(k)-sz1(k),k,:);
end

figure,imshow(img)
```

Typical mask with `roipoly` would look like -

[image]

**Output**

[image]

**Note:** User has to select exactly two points on the left side to represent the left side border of the mask and exactly two points on the right side for the right side border. Also, there must enough image pixels on top of the line to reflect over the line.

Comment: @LuisMendo Is it the cameraman in you upvoting? ;) I would take it!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the line is stored in a mask, as stated by the OP. I will assume the mask is black above the line and white below it. Here is a "fancy" way to solve the problem. :)

```
% 1. Open your image (MxNx3 matrix).
img = im2double(imread('original.png'));

% 2. Open your 'line image' as a logical array (MxNx3 matrix)
line = imread('line.png') > 0;

% 3. Now, we will "align" the upper part of the image based on the line,
%    so that the line will be straight at the bottom of the image. We will
%    do that by sorting the 'line image', moving the ones of the mask
%    above. The code was adapted from:
%    http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/28715
upper = zeros(size(line));
upper(~line) = -1;
upper = sort(upper, 'descend');
upper(upper == -1) = img(~line);

% 4. Let's concatenate both the image with it's mirror below.
imgConcat = [upper; upper(end:-1:1, :, :)];

% 5. Also, The line mask will be concatenated to it's negative, and we'll
%    invert the order of the rows.
lineConcat = [line; ~line];
lineConcat = lineConcat(end:-1:1,:,:);

% 6. Now we repeat the "alignment procedure" used on step 4 so that the
%    image will be positioned on the upper part. We will also remove the
%    lower part, now containing only zeros.
mirror = zeros(size(lineConcat));
mirror(lineConcat) = -1;
mirror = sort(mirror, 'ascend');
mirror(mirror == -1) = imgConcat(lineConcat);
mirror = mirror(1:end/2,:,:);
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSBQy.png) you see the result (step by step);

[image]

To generate that image, I used this code:

```
% Display the results, step by step (final result is in the 'mirror' matrix).
subplot(2,3,1), imshow(img, []); title('Step 1. Original image')
subplot(2,3,2), imshow(double(line), []); title('Step 2. Line image');
subplot(2,3,3), imshow(upper, []); title('Step 3. Image "alignment"');
subplot(2,3,4), imshow(imgConcat, []); title('Step 4. Mirror concatenation');
subplot(2,3,5), imshow(double(lineConcat), []); title('Step 5. Mask concatenation');
subplot(2,3,6), imshow(mirror, []); title('Step 6. Result by a final alignment');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the line is already defined, the simple way to go about this would be to scan each column and, starting at the location of the line, copy as many elements from above the line as will fit below the line, in reverse order.

So for each column `c`, let `line[c]` be the row number of the line in that column. Then

```
maxR = size(c);
c(line[c]:end) = c(line[c]-1:-1:line[c]-(maxR - line[c] + 1));
```

That part at the end, `line[c]-(maxR - line[c] + 1)` is what tells it how much to copy. It just takes the distance between the bottom of the column to the line and uses that as the number of pixels to copy.

Of course this has to be generalized to account for 3 channels, but I didn't want to clutter up the concept. Other than that, you just have to put that in a loop over all the columns, `c`.

This also assumes that there is enough data above the line to fill the area below the line. If not, you'll have to decide how to handle this case.

I'm sure there are ways to vectorize this and take out the loop, but I'll leave that to the experts :)